# Use Socket.io to fill google Area Chart - 'google.visualization.DataTable is not a constructor'

Tags: node.js, socket.io, google-visualization

I use NodeJS and Socket.io to get data from a database. I now want to fill a google area chart with these data but i kind of fail at doing it.
The data is transmitted as `Objects`. Each `Object` contains two values (datetime and value). I append these values to an array and then store them in a `DataTable`:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var socket = io();
getData();

function drawChart(dataArray) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'DateTime');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i += 2) {
        console.log(dataArray[0]);
        data.addRow([dataArray[i], dataArray[i + 1]]);
    }
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        title: "Data Visualization",
        isStacked: true,
        width: '50%',
        height: '50%',
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Data v-Axis'
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Data h-Axis'
        }
    })
}

function getData() {
    socket.emit('GET');
    socket.on('serverSent', function (data) {
        var processedData = processData(data);
        drawChart(processedData);
    })
}

function processData(data) {
    var arr = new Array();
    jQuery.each(data, function (index, object) {
        arr.push(object['datetime'], parseInt(object['value']));
    })
    return arr;
}
```

If i call my website i see the chart but without any values and the error message `google.visualization.DataTable is not a constructor´. So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `drawChart` is being called twice.
From both `google.setOnLoadCallback` and `getData`.
If `getData` is called before `google.setOnLoadCallback`,
then `google.visualization.DataTable` will not be recognized.

In addition, it is recommended to use `loader.js` vs. `jsapi`.
See [Load the Libraries](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs) for more info...

As such, please try the following...

Replace...
`<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

With...
`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

And try something like...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: init,
    packages: ['corechart']
});

function init() {
    var socket = io();
    socket.emit('GET');
    socket.on('serverSent', function (data) {
        var processedData = processData(data);
        drawChart(processedData);
    });
}

function drawChart(dataArray) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'DateTime');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i += 2) {
        console.log(dataArray[0]);
        data.addRow([dataArray[i], dataArray[i + 1]]);
    }
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        title: "Data Visualization",
        isStacked: true,
        width: '50%',
        height: '50%',
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Data v-Axis'
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Data h-Axis'
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Now i get the error `io` is not defined and that the file `C:\socket.io\socket.io.js` can't be found. Which could be true, because `socket.io` is placed in my directory in the folder `node_modules` where `npm` saves all its modules.

Comment: I am doing it the exact whay as it is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689877/cant-find-socket-io-js

Comment: if you remove everything _google charts_ related, are you able to get the data from `socket.io`? if so, you may want to switch the order of things, get data, then load _google_. if not, it may be a topic for another question...?