# How does script tag resolves path to node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was reading this Node.js In Action and there's this `index.html` which references `socket.io.js` from `node_modules` folder (I believe).

How does the following script tag resolves the path to the `socket.io.js` when the `node_modules` folder is one directory up from where the `index.html` resides?

The script tag:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find socket.io.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689877/cant-find-socket-io-js)

Comment: Thanks JordanHendrix but in my case, there is no error saying the file cannot find. From my end, everything works but I want to understand how the script tag managed to locate the socket.io.js inside the node_modules/socket.io directory when its not explicitly specified in the script tag. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you include a module in your file, node first looks for the module in `node_modules` folder in current directory. If it does not find it there then it moves to parent directory and looks for the module in `node_modules` present in that directory, and it keeps moving up until it finds the required module.

Answer (score 0):

- Socket.io reads the content of the `socket.io-client/socket.io.js` file into a variable.
- Socket.io has access to your app's http server, it then listens to requests that would match the URL of something like '/socket.io/socket.io.js' and responds with the contents of that variable above

You can see this in the [socket.io source code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io):

- [Reading the .js source code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/index.js#L27)
- [Serving the .js file](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/index.js#L267)

Comment: Thanks Saeed, so are you saying that '/socket.io/socket.io.js' matches the actual directory of where the socket.io.js really resides (i.e., node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Samot, No the physical file path and the URL do not need to match.  The physical file comes from another npm package called socket.io-client which socket.io package depends on.  
  
So the file is located under `node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js`

Comment: Ok Thanks Saeed. So is it safe and correct to say that the '/socket.io/socket.io.js' refers to 'node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js' then? Thanks in advance

Comment: "So the file is located under node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js " - I can't find this directory though...Is it under my project directory? Thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely safe.  While it is currently served from this location, in the future socket.io might move it to a different location but still serve it from the same URL.  If you let me know what you're trying to achieve, I might be able to help you better.

Comment: Under my project directory, all i can find is node_modules/mime and node_modules/socket.io

Comment: If you have an older version of NPM, it might be under `node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Saeed. Thanks for your prompt responses! I appreciate it.