# Socket.io doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, serverside-javascript

This is my server.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app).listen(8080,function(){
 console.log('working');
  });
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
 });

io.on('connection',function(socket){
console.log('someone connected');
});
```

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>


 <script>
    var socket = io();


</script>

</body>
 </html>
```

I think I did it correctly like in its site but when I run it on node and look at localhost:8080 I can't see 'someone connected' sentence in console.Where's the problem or what can be the problem?

Comment: you are using `server.js` in client??

Comment: socket = io.connect() ; :)

Comment: This `<script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>` is not correct.  It should be `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`.  You are not pointing to where the file is on your server.  You are using the path that socket.io has installed a route for so it can then get the file from the proper location and serve it back to the client.

Answer (score 3):

I set up your code on my server but changed the script source of the `index.html` file to:

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

I can get it logging `someone connected` on the server.

This is taken from the top example on the [socket.io website](http://socket.io/docs/).  I guess the file path resolution must be handled somewhere in the `socket.io` server source code.

See also: [Can't find socket.io.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689877/cant-find-socket-io-js)

Answer (score 1):

Try this , Its working for me

Server.js(server side)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  console.log(__dirname + " dir name");
});


io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  socket.on("join", function(name) {
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {

  });
});

http.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

In client side

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080");

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        //connect
    });

socket.emit("join", 'user1');
```